# Howto specify format of Restlet-response in browser?

Tags: url, rest, restlet

i've started to introduce myself into REST. I use as REST-framework Restlet.
I have defined a resource with methods for the GET with several response formats like

```
@Get("xml")
@Get("json")
```

I now want to test my defined response-formats with my browser, but I don't know which parameter I have to specify in my URL to get the format. 
Something like:

```
http://localhost:8182/members?type=xml
```

I've tried some param-names, but I couldn't find the right param-name. I know that there must be such a parameter, because I've seen it already in an URL, but i forgot the name and couldn't find it in the net.
How is the name of this parameter when using restlet?

I would be pleased, if somebody can help me,
thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Martin uses the Restlet API which defines its own simpler annotations (such ash @Get). The Restlet Framework does support JAX-RS API and annotations (such as @GET, @Produces, etc.) but as part of an extension.

To select the media type in your browser you need to use the "media=xml" query parameter instead of "type=xml", but this can be configured in the TunnelService of your Restlet Application instance.

Hope this helps. For further help, please use the Restlet mailing list:
http://www.restlet.org/community/lists

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the "Accept" header in your request to "text/xml" or "text/json".

I also thought if you wanted to return a resource in a certain mime-type you used the `@Produces("text")` annotation, not the @GET (unless this is the new way).  Hmm..I see according to the API you can do it with the @GET.

I believe the URI parameter you are looking for is ?media=json

Answer (score 0):

I'm on example project *org.restlet.example.serialization.gae.server*
and this thread helped me, so I've done small change (just added **"json"** in quotes and parenthesis) to get JSON response:

```
@Get("json")
public Contact retrieve() {
    return contact;
}
```